# Update label text before and after long running code

Tags: c#

In my button listener, I have to do  things.

1) Update the label text

```
StatusLabel.Text= "start";
```

2) process work, a little bit longer time.

3) Update the label text

```
StatusLabel.Text="end";
```

Why can I see "end" only?

I know the work should not run in UI thread, but how to do it in C#?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this asynchronous.

You can use something like this:

```
StatusLabel.Text= "start";

Task.Factory.StartNew( () => YourHeavyTask() ).ContinueWith( (n) => this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { StatusLabel.Text = "end"; }) );
```

This sample uses [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is newer (and some people say better) then using `BackgroundWorker`, etc.

Personally I think both are good, depending on which you feel more comfortable with. I would suggest TPL when you have some more complex tasks depending on another or when they can run in parallel.

Comment: @Jacob: thanks for the edit, the label name is actually wrong in the question. Corrected that too.

Comment: Note that if you run that under the debugger, you will get an InvalidOperationException because of an invalid cross-thread operation. You should be using BeginInvoke() or Invoke() to call a method or Action to set the text.

Comment: @MatthewWatson: for which part do you mean? If you mean the `ContinueWith` part, this is what the docs say:  "the synchronous continuation will run on the thread calling ContinueWith"

Comment: Aye, the `ContinueWith()` will be called from the thread started by `StartNew()`, which isn't the UI thread. Run it under the debugger and you'll see what I mean (it will not show an error if not run under the debugger, because it's just a warning condition)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: Thanks for the hint. I tested it and you are right, updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you're running step #2 sequentially after 1 and before 3 within the same thread. The problem with this is that the code is never "yielding" control, so the application doesn't have a chance to draw the text change.

Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or similar class in order to run step #2 in a separate thread to free up your UI thread.

**Update**:

I'd use a `Task` as Patrick suggests. If you do want to use BackgroundWorker, here's a sample of what you could do:

```
StatusLabel.Text = "start";

var worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += (s, e) => YourHeavyTask();
worker.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) => StatusLabel.Text = "end";
worker.RunWorkerAsync();
```